# Taylor expansion of $f(x,y)=xy-x+2x^3-yx^3$ about (0,1)...

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am asked to expand $f(x,y)=xy-x+2x^3-yx^3$ about (0,1) up to second order:

First I found the required derivatives, and their values at (0,1),

$ f_x=y-1+6x^2-3yx^2=0$

$f_y=x-x^3=0$

$f_{xx}=12x-6yx=0$

$f_{xy}=1-3x^2=1$

$f_{yy}= 0$

Then I substituted them into the Taylor expansion formula for two variables up to second order:

$f(x,y)= f+(xf_x+yf_y)+\frac{1}{2!}(x^2f_{xx}+ 2xy f_{xy}+y^2f_{yy}$)

$=\frac{1}{2}(2xy)$

$=xy$

This is my first time applying the Taylor expansion formula for two variables, having done the Taylor expansion before for one variable, the answer I got here doesn't look right to me. Is it correct? If not, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: What you did there is for the expansion about $(0,0)$, not $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Kaster, No, since the derivatives were calculated at $(0,1)$.

Comment: @mickep, $yf_y$ is the term when $y_0 = 0$, it should be $(y-1)f_y$. Well, you already know that based on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a polynomial, it might be easier to work with the expression to write it as a polynomial in $x$ and $y-1$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
xy-x+2x^3-yx^3&=x(y-1+1)-x+2x^3-(y-1+1)x^3\\
&=x(y-1)+x^3-(y-1)x^3.
\end{aligned}
$$
We throw away the terms that have degree higher than two, and the result is
$$
x(y-1).
$$

**Edit**
To answer your question, you differentiate correctly, but the formula for the Taylor polynomial is
$$
f(0,1)+xf'_x(0,1)+(y-1)f'_y(0,1)+\frac{1}{2!}\bigl(x^2 f''_{xx}(0,1)+2x(y-1)f''_{xy}(0,1)+(y-1)^2f''_{yy}(0,1)\bigr)
$$

Comment: So do I substitute (y-1) for every y stated in the Taylor expansion formula I wrote above? Is this only for when looking at the expansion about point (0,1)? If I was looking at the expansion about the point (1,2), would I replace every x with (x-1) and every y with (y-2) in my initial formula?

Comment: Indeed, that is how it works (just as in one dimension).